# Mac Terminal Strange Behaviour (no newline when hitting enter, no visible text )

Tags: macos, bash, terminal

I'm on Mac OS X 10.11.3 My terminal looks like this:

```
[Fabian@MacBook-Pro] > 
[Fabian@MacBook-Pro] > pyspark
Python 2.7.11 (default, Jan 29 2016, 17:48:19) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 7.0.2 (clang-700.1.81)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
16/03/17 10:08:22 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library     for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Welcome to

      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /__ / .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 1.6.1
      /_/

Using Python version 2.7.11 (default, Jan 29 2016 17:48:19)
SparkContext available as sc, HiveContext available as sqlContext.
>>> print 'hello'
>>> hello

>>> quit()
>>> [Fabian@MacBook-Pro] > [Fabian@MacBook-Pro] > [Fabian@MacBook-Pro] > [Fabian@MacBook-Pro] > -bash:     printsf: command not found
```

in the first line I press enter, and as you see, the prompt starts at another line, then I launch pyspark, do something and quit, then when I return to the prompt I press enter and as you can see, the prompt doesn't appear in a newline! I actually type and nothing is printed to the screen, however the commands are executed as you can see

```
 -bash:     printsf: command not found
```

my .bash_profile (located in /Users/Fabian folder) looks like this

```
# Setting PATH for Python 3.4
# The orginal version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/Users/Fabian/Library/Python

##
# Your previous /Users/Fabian/.bash_profile file was backed up as /Users/Fabian/.bash_profile.macports-saved_2016-02-07_at_11:26:24
##

# MacPorts Installer addition on 2016-02-07_at_11:26:24: adding an appropriate PATH variable for use with MacPorts.
export PATH="/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH"
# Finished adapting your PATH environment variable for use with MacPorts.

export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)
export PATH=$PATH:/Users/Fabian/apache-maven-3.3.9/bin
export PS1="[\u@\h] > "
export PATH=$PATH:/Users/Fabian/spark-1.6.1-bin-hadoop2.6/bin
```

How Can I fix this behavior??
Thanks!

Comment: After you exit, it looks like pyspark isn't resetting your terminal properly. Try typing the following: `^Jstty sane^J` (those are Ctrl-J's) to reset your tty settings to something usable. Or alternately, force a terminal reset with: `^Jreset^J` If you can't figure out how to make pyspark behave, you might be able to get away with wrapping it in an alias in your .bashrc: `alias pyspark="pyspark;reset"`

Comment: That actually did the trick! (the stty sane part)thank you! Although it is not a permanent solution, it is really helpful.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

As noted in comments (and as described by OP), the expected newline after each message was lost.  That is because the application changed the terminal I/O modes dealing with carriage-return / line-feed, e.g.,

- pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> (which is a carriage return) was not translated into a newline (actually a line-feed), and
- newlines sent from the computer were not translated into carriage return / line-feed.

However, on "any" keyboard, you can type a *newline* by pressing <kbd>control</kbd><kbd>J</kbd>.  The usual fixes apply pressing <kbd>control</kbd><kbd>J</kbd> first to get a prompt, and completing the command with pressing <kbd>control</kbd><kbd>J</kbd>):

- [`stty sane`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/stty.html) (resets the terminal driver)
- [`reset`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/tset.1.html) (resets the terminal driver as well as asking the terminal to reset itself).

Comment: Thanks for recycling! Note that I put this information in a comment rather than an answer because it's *not an answer*. It doesn't fix the OP's problem. If you were to come up with an actual solution, it might be worthy of a checkmark. As it is, it's not.

Comment: @Graham `stty sane` _is_ an actual solution though. It seems to have worked for OP and it has also worked for me.

Comment: I don't think it is a solution, it is a workaround. A solution, for me, would be a strategy to identify what is causing the terminal to exhibit this behavior in order to be able to fix the cause, so there is no need to reset the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

This can be caused by an escape character that when printed to the terminal causes it to go nuts.
It usually helps if you close this terminal window and open a new one. Maybe `pyspark` is using some escape codes (for color or design) and then forgets to revert its changes. 
You can try running `pyspark` with a terminal type of `dumb` instead of `xterm-256color`. This can be done via the `$TERM` Environment Variable. Try doing `echo $TERM` before running `pyspark`.

Comment: echo $TERM prints xterm-256color, then I change it with export TERM=dumb, the same behavior is still there after running pyspark. If I close and open a new window it goes back to normal.

Comment: same behavior after running pyspark with this line

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with python 2.7.12 installed with macport. This might have been a coincidence, because I've tried many things, but "sudo port install py27-readline" fixed the problem for me.